# Convergence of expectation of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem:

Let $Q_n$ denote a sequence of random variables such that
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{Q_n}{n}] \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$
and
$\frac{Q_n}{n} \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$
with probability one.

I have function $g_n(\cdot)$ and want to prove that
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{g_n(Q_n)}{Q_n}] \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha$

I have been able to prove that $\frac{g_n(f(n))}{f(n)} \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha$
for all functions
$f(\cdot)$
with
$ \frac{f(n)}{n} \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0.$
I'm not sure how to account for the probability that $Q_n$ is of size $O(n)$. Even though this converges to zero it may have non-zero contribution to the expectation (even in the limit). Is there a theorem that may give some requirements for $Q_n$ that need to hold for such a convergence?

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. Why not specify exactly what your $Q_n, f,g $ are ?

Comment: The problem is that $g$ is a really nasty function of which I only really know how it behaves asymptotically as $n$ goes to infinity, in fsct it should have also been indexed by $n$ here. The functions $f$ can be any sublinear function here (i.e. $f(n)/n \rightarrow 0$, e.g. $log(n)$ or $\sqrt{n}$). The random variable $Q_n$ denotes the number of jobs in equilibrium for a queueing system with $n$ servers in light-traffic where the arrival rate per server converges to zero.